# Latest version of NodeJS, supported by Zurb Foundation 6 (v6.4.3)?

Tags: node.js, npm, zurb-foundation, version

Which is the highest NodeJS version supported by the current (6.4.3) Zurb Foundation for Sites 6?

According to my "research", the current [foundation-sites](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/c7a6f44da00b7c17b8d5d2da6e15cfb4e1aac8b4/package.json), depends on `"gulp-sass": "^4.0.1"`, [which in turn depends on](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/blob/fa670c64b23cbbc9f595fb14386205df7b382fdc/package.json) `"node-sass": "^4.8.3"`.

Now according to [this node-sass issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2345), any version before 4.9.X doesn't support node 10 or later.

### Am I correct in concluding that `foundation-sites` supports node 8 as the highest nodeJS version?

---

P.S. Did I miss it, or does Zurb completely omit mentioning supported Node versions anywhere on their site/github?

Comment: You can easily upgrade / update gulp-sass and node-sass for better Node.js support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version is 10.14.2 but at the time of Foundation 6.4.3 latest node version was 8+ which is tested.

Answer (score 1):

We test against 6, 8, 10 and latest (11) on macOS, Linux and Windows. See https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/.travis.yml